# Disable slide transitions on a particular element in PowerPoint

Tags: slideshow, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

Basically I have the same title on two consecutive slides and I don't want the title to do a slide transition as it doesn't change. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: So you basically want the title of the slide to stay still while the slide transition occurs? Am I right?

Comment: @Ayan. Correct. The transition shouldn't occur between the slides.

Comment: This is where I am getting confused. You want to turn off the slide transition when ever the title of the slides are same?

OR

You want to keep the slide transition but want the title to stay still while it occurs?

Comment: @Ayan I realize i may have phrased my previous comment badly. I meant the latter of your two interpretations.

Answer (score 1):

Slide transitions are applied on the entire slide including all its contents (Title, Pictures, Text, Charts, etc.). So you cannot exclude a particular object on a slide from the transition.

However you can mimic the effect that you are looking for by applying a suitable slide transition between the slides containing the common title. For example the Wipe transitions is a very good one for this kind of scenario. If you place the title on both the slides in the exact same position and apply the wipe transition it will appear as if the content just changed but the title stayed still.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do a transition on the second slide. 
If you want the slide's contents to appear in a non-boring way,
select all the elements except for the title and use Animations.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the elements you want to remain static into a slide layout and then apply that layout to the slides before and after the transition, the layout elements will remain static while the content of the slides moves with the pan transition.